# Can we know the region in the xy-plane given this information?

Tags: general-topology

Consider a closed smooth bounded curve enclosing a region S in the XY-plane. Suppose that we know the length of all lines which is the intersection of S with an infinite line parallell to the x-axis. And we know the same for the y-axis. Can we reconstruct S using only this data? 
If not, suppose we know the same for some other axes, is there a finite set of axis enough to reconstruct S?

Comment: There are infinitely many lines from any point on S to the axes. Do you mean the shortest path?

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote

Comment: So we know *all* the lines from every point S to every point on each infinite line?

Comment: If we pick a segment which is the intersection of any line paralell to the x-axis and S, then we know its length

Comment: He is saying we know two functions: the function $f(a) = \text{Length}(S \cap (\{a\} \times \mathbb{R}))$; and the function $g(b) = \text{Length}(S \cap (\mathbb{R} \times \{b\}))$.

Comment: I see 2 interpretations of the Q.  For short, let $V(x)=S\cap (\{x\}\times R).$ For $V(x)=\phi$ let $f(x)=-1.$ When $V(x)\ne \phi$  let $f(x)=\sup \{|y-z|: (x,y),(x,z)\in S\}.$  Now does knowing the lengths of all the vertical lines' intersections with $S$ mean that we know the function $f$ or that we only know the set $\{f(x) :x\in R\}$?

Comment: Amending my previous comment, I am further uncertain if we are looking at the function $f,$ , when $V(x)\ne \phi, $ or the1-dimensional  measure  $\mu^1 (V(x)),$ as being  the length of the intersection of $S$ with the vertical line thru $x.$ This intersection may have multiple components. Also I should have said $f(x)=0$ when $V(x)=\phi.$  As before, do we know the function $g(x)=\mu^1(V(x))$ or just $\{g(x):x\in R\}$?

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible to reconstruct such a shape. For instance, if you take a rectangle $A$ for which the sides form a $45°$ angle with the $XY$-axis, and rotate it by $90°$ to obtain a rectangle $B$, then the intersection of any line parallel to the x or y axis with $A$ will have the same length than the intersection with $B$.

For the generalization, I have no idea.

Comment: I was temporarily confused by what you meant by "permute its sides" (I thought you meant something like relabeling the vertices, which would not change the shape itself). I would understand the operation better as "rotate the rectangle by $90^\circ$".

Comment: You are right, I edited it.

Answer (score -1):

We know the function $f(x)$, where $x$ is a point on the $x$ axis, defined as the length of the intersection of, the line paralell to the $y$-axis which goes through $x$, with the set $S$, so it can have multiple components and we know the total length. I am owner of question

Comment: It is better to edit your own question to include this information. This post will probably get deleted soon.